# r ggplot2 annotate pointrange and segment in single facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I am creating a 3 facet plot with `ggplot` with the following data

```
library(ggplot2)

test<-as.data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4))
colnames(test)<-"e12"
test$e23<-c(NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5)
test$e34<-c(NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,3,4,5,6)
test$Age<-c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
test$facet<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)

ggplot(test, aes(x=Age)) + 
  facet_grid( ~ facet) +
  geom_line(aes(y = e12), size=0.25, colour="red", linetype="dashed") +
  geom_point(aes(y = e12), size=2.5, shape=21, fill="red", colour=NA) +
  geom_line(aes(y = e23), size=0.25, colour="blue", linetype="dashed") +
  geom_point(aes(y = e23), size=2.5, shape=21, fill="blue", colour=NA) +
  geom_line(aes(y = e34), size=0.25, colour="green", linetype="dashed") +
  geom_point(aes(y = e34), size=2.5, shape=21, fill="green", colour=NA) +
  annotate("pointrange", x=3.05, y=6.1, ymin=6.1, ymax=6.1, colour="red", size=0.5) +
  annotate("segment", x=2.8, xend=3.4, y=6.1, yend=6.1, colour="red", size=0.5, linetype="dashed") +
  annotate("text", x=3.6, y=6.1, parse=T, label="e[1%;%2]", size=3.1, family="Calibri", colour="black") +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=rel(1)),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill="white", colour="white", size=1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0.5,4.5), breaks=seq(1, 4, 1), minor_breaks=seq(1, 4, 1), expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,6.5), breaks=seq(0, 6.5, 1), minor_breaks=seq(0,6.5,0.2), expand = c(0, 0))
```

However, this poses 2 problems:

1. I would like the annotations (pointrange, segment and text) to appear in just one facet. I have seen how to create a dataframe to annotate only text in a single facet, but would like to know if this is possible for segments and pointranges.
2. The text should read e1;2 with 1;2 in subscript - although putting the ";" in plotmath causes errors.

[image]

Comment: You are not really using ggplot2 the way it should be used: there is really no need to plot every line separately as you do. Having said that, I am not sure what your desired result really is. If the plot that you find [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1551392/Rplot.png) will do, I'm happy to tell you how I did it. Just let me know.

Comment: Thanks, this would be an appropriate solution, although with the legend overlapping the right hand facet using `legend.position` would be prefered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To produce the plot exactly as you want it might be difficult, but often it is good not to mess to much around with details of ggplot. So I can show you how to produce the following plot:

[image]
The way you are using gpgplot is not how it is (as far as I understand) intended to be used. You are writing a command for each line that you want to plot. But the idea of ggplot is to put all the data into a data frame and then map columns of the data frame to graphical elements. You might find the following resources helpful: the [ggplot2 page](http://www.ggplot2.org) and [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/index.html), where you find tons of good examples with ggplot2.

The first step is thus to prepare the data such that the plot can be done. Assuming that `test` is defined as in your example, the following code will format the data appropriately:

```
library(reshape2)
plot.test <- melt(test,id=c("Age","facet"))
plot.test <- subset(plot.test,!is.na(value))
```

Look at `plot.test` and the documentation of `melt` to understand this step better. The first line puts the data in a different shape. Instead of one column per curve (e_12,e_23,e_34), you then have one column with all the values and a column that indicates, to which curve the value belongs. The second line then throws away all the undefined values, which are not needed.

Now that the data is ready, the plot can be produced as follows:

```
e.labs <- c(expression(e["1;2"]),expression(e["2;3"]),expression(e["3;4"]))

ggplot(plot.test,aes(x=Age,y=value,colour=variable)) +
  facet_grid(.~facet) +
  geom_line(size=0.25, linetype="dashed") + 
  geom_point(size=2.5) + 
  theme(strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=rel(1)),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill="white", colour="white", size=1),
        legend.position=c(0.93,0.15)) +
  scale_colour_discrete(labels=e.labs)
```

As you see, `geom_line` and `geom_point` both need only be called once. The mapping of the data is done inside the `ggplot` command. It says that the variable `Age` should be used as the x-axis, and the variable `value` (which contains the data from the columns `e_12` etc. from your original data frame) should be used as the y-axis. The column `variable`, which states whether the data comes from the `e_12`, `e_23`, or `e_34` column, is used to set different colours. Since theses mappings are the same for points and lines, they can be defined globally in `ggplot()` instead of inside the `geom_` functions.

If you use `ggplot` correctly, that is by assigning columns to graphical objects, legends are produced automatically. The code contains only two statements to customize the legend: `scale_colour_discrete` is used to change the labels in the legend, `legend.position` inside `theme` is used to move the legend on the plot as you requested.

If you also wanted to replace the y-axis labels and the legend title by something meaningful, you can use the `labs` function. Simply add the following to your plot

```
+ labs(y="my y label",colour="my legend title")
```

I have not bothered to include your customisation of the x- and y-axis, as it seems that you already know how to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot - much more efficient! I think getting to understand `melt`will help me a lot as organising my dataframes seem to be a big part of the problem.